# Como convertir vocales a mayusculas?

Tags: c#

Tengo este arreglo quisiera convertir solo las vocales de cada palabra en mayúsculas pero me convierte toda la oración en mayúscula 
cualquier ayuda es bienvenida, gracias

```
 public static void BocalesMayusculas()
 {
      string[] names = { "Casa", "Perro", "Bicicleta", "Carro", "Gato", "Puerta" };

      var consulta = from n in names
                  where n.Contains("a") || n.Contains("e") ||n.Contains("i") || n.Contains("o") || n.Contains("u")
      select n.ToUpper();


      foreach (var nombre in consulta)
      {   
          Console.WriteLine(nombre);
      }
  }
```

Comment: Es que estas haciendo un ToUpper de toda la palabra no de la vocal solo.

Comment: Entonces como podría seleccionar solo las letras en especifico?

Comment: Para cada palabra ve caracter a caracter y haz el ToUpper de ese caracter solo.

Comment: como haria algo asi?

Comment: Podrías usar [Regex.replace](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.replace?view=netframework-4.8). O puedes recorrer la cadena de texto carácter por carácter y reemplazar. Saludos

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lo único que debes hacer es recorrer el array y usar [`Replace`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.string.replace?view=netframework-4.8) para reemplazar las minusculas por su correspondiente mayúscula:

```
string[] names = { "Casa", "Perro", "Bicicleta", "Carro", "Gato", "Puerta" };

for (int i=0;i<names.Length;i++)
{
    names[i] = names[i].ToLower().Replace("a", "A").Replace("e", "E").Replace("i", "I").Replace("o", "O").Replace("u", "U");
    Console.WriteLine(names[i]);
}
```

Otra opción es hacer el `Replace` en tu consulta linq. Simplemente modifícala a lo siguiente:

```
var consulta = from nam in names
               select nam.ToLower().Replace("a", "A").Replace("e", "E").Replace("i", "I").Replace("o", "O").Replace("u", "U");
```

Answer (score 2):

Podrías directamente cuando recoges todas las palabras de la lista, cambiar las vocales a la hora de pintarlas:

```cs
public static void BocalesMayusculas()
{
  string[] names = { "Casa", "Perro", "Bicicleta", "Carro", "Gato", "Puerta" };

  var consulta = from n in names
  where n.Contains("a") || n.Contains("e") ||n.Contains("i") || n.Contains("o") || n.Contains("u")
  select n;
  foreach (string nombre in consulta)
  { 
    string aux = nombre;  
    aux = aux.Replace("a","A");
    aux = aux.Replace("e","E");
    aux = aux.Replace("i","I");
    aux = aux.Replace("o","O");
    aux = aux.Replace("u","U");
    Console.WriteLine(aux);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Espero este código te sirva para lo que necesitas.
Saludos.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        List<string> listaNombres = VocalesMayuscula();

        foreach (var nombre in listaNombres)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(nombre);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();


    }

    private static bool esVocal(char v)
    {
        string vocales = "aeiou";

        if (vocales.Contains(v))
            return true;


        return false;

    }

    private static List<string> VocalesMayuscula()
    {
        List<string> nombresConVocalesMayusculas = new List<string>();
        string[] nombres = { "Casa", "Perro", "Bicicleta", "Carro", "Gato", "Puerta" };

        foreach (var nombre in nombres)
        {
            string nuevoNombre = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < nombre.Length; i++)
            {

                char letra = nombre[i];
                if (esVocal(letra))
                {
                    char vocal = Char.ToUpper(letra);
                    nuevoNombre += vocal;
                }
                else
                {
                    nuevoNombre += letra;
                }
            }

            nombresConVocalesMayusculas.Add(nuevoNombre);
        }

        return nombresConVocalesMayusculas;

    }
```